# Obter informações da página sem estar logado no facebook, somente pelo token

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou criando um sistema de postagem para o facebook e está tudo certo, a não ser por uma coisa. Quando deslogo do facebook pelo sistema que estou fazendo, algumas funções não funcionam, por mais que eu passe o token de acesso do usuário ou da página.

Estou usando uma biblioteca do **Facebook SDK** para **Codeigniter**:

```
//METODO, POINT, PARAMS, TOKEN
$query = $this->request('get', '/'.$idPage, null, $row->token);
```

O que ele me retorna é:

> You must provide an access token.

Eu preciso funcionando, pois o sistema terá o `CRON` e precisa fazer as postagens na página sem o usuário estar logado

As permissões que estou obtendo são:

- manage_pages
- publish_pages
- pages_show_list
- public_profile
- publish_actions
- email
- user_managed_groups
- user_posts
- user_likes

Comment: Para todas as requisições do Facebook é necessário informar o `access_token` do usuário. Basta armazenar o `access_token` e utiliza-lo no cron normalmente, não há nenhum mistério nisto. O quarto parametro (`$row->token`) parece ser o `token`, se for basta pegar o `token` armazenado e utiliza-lo normalmente.

Comment: @Inkeliz Sim, essa variável é o token, mas mesmo passando o token para o `$this->request` ele não funciona. Tentei passar do usuário e da página e nenhuma funciona.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUÇÃO ENCONTRADA!**

A função `request()` faz vários tipos de requisição ao facebook. Quando uso a `POST` é necessário passar os parâmetros, sendo assim:

```
$query = $this->request('post', '/'.$idPage, $parametros, $row->token);
```

Como eu estou tentando fazer um `GET`, então no lugar dos `$parametros` eu preciso enviar o token diretamente:

```
$query = $this->request('get', '/'.$idPage, $row->token);
```

Dessa forma funcionou.

> Link da Library para o CodeIgniter 3.x:
>   https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter